# Type signatures are only allowed in patterns with ScopedTypeVariables - using where without curly braces

Tags: haskell, where-clause

I am facing the following problem.
When I am trying to compile the function

```
myFunction :: Int -> Int -> Int
myFunction x y = myVar1
     where {myVar1 :: Int;
            myVar1 = 1}
```

everything works fine. However, when I am not using the curly braces and trying to indentate properly

```
myFunction :: Int -> Int -> Int
myFunction x y = myVar1
     where myVar1 :: Int
           myVar1 = 1
```

I get the error

```
Illegal type signature: `Int myVar1'
      Type signatures are only allowed in patterns with ScopedTypeVariables
```

Could anyone please tell me why that is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is likely an indentation errors, since the compiler sees `Int myVar1`, so it sees `myVar1` as a type parameter instead of the a new line. Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: You are mixing TABs and spaces on the same line. Haskell effectively reads `myVar1 :: Int myVar1 = 1` as if it were written on the same line. Indent properly, e.g. using only spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces, indeed, if we work with Unicode's control pictures, we see:

```
myFunction :: Int -> Int -> Int
myFunction␣x␣y␣=␣myVar1
␣␣␣␣␣where␣myVar1␣::␣Int
␉␣␣␣␣␣␣␣myVar1␣=␣1
```

Notice the horizontal tab (`␉`) at the left side. Mixing tabs and spaces will very often result in compiler errors, since in this specific case, the Haskell compiler sees this as a type `myVar1 :: Int myVar1`, and hence the error.

You thus should only use spaces, like:

```
myFunction :: Int -> Int -> Int
myFunction x y = myVar1
      where myVar1 :: Int
            myVar1 = 1
```

where if we use control pictures, we only see spaces and the column matches whith that of the `myVar1 :: Int` part.

```
myFunction :: Int -> Int -> Int
myFunction␣x␣y␣=␣myVar1
␣␣␣␣␣where␣myVar1␣::␣Int
␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣myVar1␣=␣1
```